# Load a JSON document and sort it on one or more values in key:value pairs with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting

I want to load an external JSON object and sort based on one or more key:value pairs.
For example using the JSON below I might need to sort on category1 and then type.

I've tried `array.sort()` but no matter what I throw at it my data is never sorted; It's always output in the same order as in the JSON file.

```
{
  "books": [
    {
      "sku": "{1234}",
      "title": "Moby Dick",
      "type": "paperback",
      "category1": "fiction",
      "category2": "classic",
      "category3": "",
      "image": "",
      "ctaLabel": "Learn More"
    },
    {
      "sku": "{5678}",
      "title": "1984",
      "type": "hardcover",
      "category1": "fiction",
      "category2": "",
      "category3": "",
      "image": "",
      "ctaLabel": "Learn More"
    },
    {
      "sku": "{5678}",
      "title": "Another Title",
      "type": "paperback",
      "category1": "nonfiction",
      "category2": "youngadult",
      "category3": "",
      "image": "",
      "ctaLabel": "Learn More"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('books.json', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var items = data.books.map(function (item) {
            return item.sku + ': ' + item.title;
        });
        if (items.length) {
            var content = '<li>' + items.join('</li><li>') + '</li>';
            var list = $('<ul />').html(content);
            $("#show-data").html(list);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Look at this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047801/re-order-json-array-by-key-value

Comment: I generally don't do this because you have specified javascript/jquery in the tags, but a library like Lodash would help you tremendously if you can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4576720/3478010), you can implement a multi-level sort as follows :

```
function multiLevelSort(arr, criteria) {
    return arr.sort(function(x, y) {
        return criteria.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
            var dir = (curr.dir < 0) ? -1 : 1,
                x_ = x[curr.prop],
                y_ = y[curr.prop];
            return prev || (x_ === y_ ? 0 : x_ > y_ ? dir : -dir);
        }, 0);
    });
}
```

or, with destructuring (in Node but not yet in all browsers) :

```
function multiLevelSort(arr, criteria) {
    return arr.sort(function(x, y) {
        return criteria.reduce(function(prev, {prop, dir}) {
            dir = (dir < 0) ? -1 : 1;
            var x_ = x[prop],
                y_ = y[prop];
            return prev || (x_ === y_ ? 0 : x_ > y_ ? dir : -dir);
        }, 0);
    });
}
```

where :

- `arr` is an array of objects, as in the question.
- `criteria` is an array of objects of the following format :

```
var criteria = [
    {prop: "type", dir: 1}, // dir:1=ascending; dir:-1=descending
    {prop: "category1", dir: 1}, 
    {prop: "category2", dir: 1} 
];
```

Then simply call :

```
multiLevelSort(myArray, myCriteria);
```

Like `Array.prototype.sort()`, `myArray` will be mutated *and* returned.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gvx3u1z7/)

Comment: one quick question...what if I want to return _all_ elements and their values for each member regardless of how many sort criteria I specify?

Comment: That is exactly how `multiLevelSort()` already behaves - it sorts, not filters. In the demo, you see only columns `type`, `category1` and `category2` because these are everything necessary for demonstration. In the sorted array, all the original objects are still 100% intact, just in a different order.